# Service worker is not registering

Tags: service-worker

I'm trying to register the Service worker and getting an error:

```
DOMException: Operation failed by network issue
```

The page is hosted using github pages: https://boopathi.in/sw-demo-iss. and the source code is here https://github.com/boopathi/sw-demo-iss

I'm trying to understand what that means and how to resolve errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome seems to be trying to load/register `https://boopathi.in/sw-demo-iss/sw.bundle.js` as the service worker, but that 404s. So you probably need to fiddle with paths a bit. Maybe `register('sw.bundle.js')` will work?

Comment: +1. Erroneous dots and slashes in the registration URL can have unintended consequences. Look at them carefully when you have this issue!

Answer (score 2):

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.bundle.js', {
        scope: 'isstracker'
    }).then(function(reg) {
        console.log("Service worker registered")
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

You scoped the serviceworker to `isstracker`, that means that your serviceworker will work only for everything after the `isstracker/` path, but the demo is hosted on the `sw-demo-iss/` path. This is most probably the cause of the SecurityError you're getting:

```
"The Service Worker security policy prevented an action."
```