# Service worker installation issue: Service worker registration failed. Status code: 2

Tags: google-chrome-extension, service-worker, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

When I try to load an unpacked extension into chrome that is on Chrome Extension Manifest v3 and uses a service worker (including [chrome's sample extensions](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/api-samples/declarativeNetRequest)), I get an error message:

`Service worker registration failed. Status code: 2`

[Service worker registration failed. Status code: 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsqZj.png)

I can't find anywhere that lists these status codes or what they mean (without diving into the source code).

I downloaded Chrome Canary and the sample extensions work when loaded unpacked.

So, what does status code 2 mean? How is one supposed to recover from it?

Comment: Please see this. [Servicer Worker works for only one chrome account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75806421/servicer-worker-works-for-only-one-chrome-account)

Comment: That doesn't seem to answer the question, though it might be the same problem.

Comment: i am someone who restarts my browser rarely. it helped in this case, i don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Status Code 2 means that operation aborted - it gave up trying to load the service worker. If the same extensions are working on the same device with a different version of Chrome, it may be an issue with the chrome profile - try creating a new chrome profile (or using the guest profile) in your main browser to see if the problem is fixed.

Comment: Is there a list of error codes somewhere that I could look at? For this to be a fix, I should be able to say what the issue is, so that I can change the profile to allow service workers - idealy it would be something as easy as a setting, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: I don't know of documentation for these error codes, but "operation aborted" is a general grab bag of "something bad happened". If it _does_ work with another profile, then it would be indicative of there being a problem with the profile. The next step would be to bisect whatever is installed until you find a cause. More than likely, there is some kind of corruption in the profile, and deleting it then resyncing the account would solve it.